# Are Closed Prices just the last trade or are they averaged?

Tags: exchange-rate

Since these exchanges run 24/7, are the posted close prices (say if the chart shows 1 hour increments like on bitcoinwisdom.com) based on the last trade for that time frame?  Or are they averaged over that time frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the endpoints. You can easily see that because in a bar chart, the bars always align with either the top or the bottom of the previous bar.